# Amazon S3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am thinking to move some of the site images to host on s3, and I was wandering do I really need to use cloudfront or I can just directly use s3 url? I know  cloudfront is multi az, but it come with cost.

Will it be too crazy directly use s3 links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> cloudfront is multi az

Actually, S3 is multi-az, within a single single region.  CloudFront is global.  There are more CloudFront edge locations than there are availability zones in all regions combined.  CloudFront doesn't follow the region/availability-zone design pattern of AWS.

> but it come with cost.

Read and understand the pricing tables carefully.  Using CloudFront does have a cost, but using it also reduces the cost of using S3.

But, the answer is no, you do not technically "need" to use CloudFront in front of S3 unless you will be serving in excess of several hundred requests per second, or you want to use SSL with your own domain name to host the resources, or want to use some other feature that CloudFront offers and S3 doesn't.